# convert array to Cake\ORM\Query object in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

Here I am converting `$allProductData` to array because there I have to apply `foreach` loop and some conditions after that I am assigning `$allProductData` to pagination but I am getting error "Unable to locate an object compatible with paginate." so how can I convert array to `Cake\ORM\Query` object to pass into pagination?

```
$this->PurchaseRequisitionProducts->hasMany('PurchaseOrderProducts', [
    'bindingKey'=>'product_id',
    "foreignKey"=>'product_id'
]);
$allProductData = $this->PurchaseRequisitionProducts->find('all',[
    'contain' => ['PurchaseOrderProducts'=>function($c){
        return $c->where(['PurchaseOrderProducts.id IS NOT NULL']);
    },'PurchaseOrderProducts.PurchaseOrder'=>function($p){
        return $p->where(['PurchaseOrder.id IS NOT NULL'])
            ->where(['PurchaseOrder.is_approve'=>"Y"])
            ->where(['PurchaseOrder.po_type'=>1])
            ->where(['PurchaseOrder.status'=>1]);
    },'PurchaseOrderProducts.PurchaseOrder.CompanyMaster','PurchaseRequisition.Users.EmployeeDetails.Departments','ProductCategory','ProductSubcategory','Currency','PurchaseRequisition','ProductsMaster','Uom'] ,
    'conditions'=>[$condn,$conditions],
    //"sortWhitelist"=>["id",'EmployeeDetails.first_name','Departments.department',"pr_reference_no","pr_date",'purchase_requisition_id', "ProductsMaster.product_name","ref_price","qty","approved_qty"],
    'order'=>["PurchaseRequisitionProducts.id"=>"desc"],
])->toArray();

$pr_product = $this->paginate($allData)->toArray();
if($pr_product){
    foreach($pr_product as $key1=>$prProd){
        if(empty($prProd['purchase_order_products']) || !isset($prProd['purchase_order_products']) || $prProd['purchase_order_products']==null || $prProd['purchase_order_products']=='' || empty($prProd['purchase_order_products'])){
            unset($pr_product[$key1]);
        }

        if(isset($prProd['purchase_order_products'])){
            $supplier=[];
            $poarray=[];
            foreach($prProd['purchase_order_products'] as $key2=>$poProd){
                if($poProd['purchase_order']==null || $poProd['purchase_order']=='' || empty($poProd['purchase_order'])){
                    unset($prProd['purchase_order_products'][$key2]);
                }

                $supplier[]=$poProd['purchase_order']['supplier_id'];
                //debug($supplier);
                $companies= $this->CompanyMaster->find('list', [
                    'keyField' => 'id','valueField' => 'Company_name',
                    'conditions'=>['id IN'=>$supplier],
                ])->toArray();
                $pr_product[$key1]['supplier']=$companies;
            }

            if(empty($prProd['supplier'])){
                unset($pr_product[$key1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding to array in find all query you should add it on the result of pagination like:

```
   $allProductData = $this->PurchaseRequisitionProducts->find('all',[
        'contain' => ['PurchaseOrderProducts']
    ]);// remove toArray() from here
    $pr_product = $this->paginate($allProductData)->toArray(); // AddtoArray() here
```

OR you can try like this:

```
 $paginate = [
                    'contain' => ['PurchaseOrderProducts'],
                    'limit' => 10
                ];
    $this->set('data', $this->Paginator->paginate($this->PurchaseRequisitionProducts->find('all'), $paginate)->toArray());
```

Comment: But before to add on pagination I have do some unset conditions in the find all.

Comment: What do you want to unset?

Comment: I have add my complete code where I am doing too many unset under foreach loop can you please check.

Comment: You can pass these conditions in query. Anyway just remove toArray() from the $allProductData and set pagination data like $this->set('paginationData',  $pr_product); after unsetting variables.

Comment: ok sure, and you dont need to unset the data, you can use the column name in condition directly

Comment: I am trying to add column name directly in condition like 'conditions'=>[ 'PurchaseOrder.id IS NOT NULL'] but I am getting error Column not found error.

Comment: The id column in your PurchaseOrders table is presumably never actually going to be null. What you want is more likely along the lines of `PurchaseOrderProducts.purchase_order_id IS NOT NULL`, though the details will depend on your particular schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way also, you have to remove `toArray()` in order to make pagination work.

```
$allProductData = $this->PurchaseRequisitionProducts->find('all')->contain(['PurchaseOrderProducts']);
$pr_product = $this->paginate($allProductData);
```

Also, define this public variable

```
public $paginate = [
    'limit' => 25,
    'order' => [
        'TableName.columnName' => 'asc' //not mandatory
    ]
];
```

Comment: when I am doing find all after that I have apply some unset conditions in the find all then I have to assign the variable for paginate

Comment: `unset conditions` like? What do you mean by that?

Comment: when I am getting all data then I have to apply foreach loop and remove some of the array

Comment: you don't need to do that, define that variable in the class of your controller it will take care of it automatically. define `limit` according to the data you need.

Comment: I have add my complete code where I am doing too many unset under foreach loop can you please check.